# Quadratic reciprocity for odd integers

Tags: quadratic-reciprocity

I have a book that proves the three laws of quadratic reciprocity for primes i.e  $\left(\frac{-1}p\right)=1$ if $p=1\mod4$ and $-1$ if $p=3\mod4$, where $p$ is prime, etc.
But in the end the book says that the three laws are also true for arbitary odd integers.

> Why is that true?

Thank you.

Comment: There's an extension of the Legendre symbol (the one you know about, where $p$ is prime) to something called the Jacobi symbol. You can do a search for that, and probably find all your questions answered. Then you can post an answer to your own question. That's encouraged on this site.